# Solving for x with matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -5 & -9  \\
        -6 & -2  \\
        \end{bmatrix}   X +   \begin{bmatrix}
        -3 & 2  \\
        -9 & -3  \\
        \end{bmatrix}   =  \begin{bmatrix}
        -9 & -7  \\
        -2 & -3  \\
        \end{bmatrix}   X
$$

I am asked to solve for matrix X

I combine the x to the right side and get
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -14 & -16  \\
        -8 & -6  \\
        \end{bmatrix}   X
$$

Then I move the other matrix to the right and get

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -14 & -16  \\
        -8 & -6  \\
        \end{bmatrix}   X = \begin{bmatrix}
        3 & -2  \\
        9 &  3  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

I then proceed to find the inverse of the x coefficient matrix which comes out to be \begin{bmatrix}
        6/44 & -16/44  \\
        -8/44 & 14/44  \\
        \end{bmatrix}

I know this is the correct inverse because when I multiply it by the original x coefficient matrix I get the identity matrix.

Now as far as I'm aware, all that's left is multiplying the inverse by the right side, but when I do that, my homework system tells me that I'm wrong. Where is the mistake? This is the answer that I get
\begin{bmatrix}
        -63/22 & -15/11  \\
        51/22 & 29/22  \\
        \end{bmatrix}

Comment: when you "move" something to the other side it goes there with minus like $ -5x+-3=-9x$ is equivalent to $-3 = -4x $  not $ -3=-14x $

Comment: @Gyfe Is x a scalar or a matrix?

Comment: It's a matrix, sorry for confusion

Comment: write X for a matrix to clarify this confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a sign error, as

$$ \left( \begin{pmatrix} -5 & -9 \\ -6 & -2 \end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix} -9 & -7 \\ -2 & -3 \end{pmatrix} \right) X = \begin{pmatrix} 4 & -2 \\ -4 & 1 \end{pmatrix}X = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & -2 \\ 9 & 3 \end{pmatrix}.  $$

Comment: If I multiply the inverse by your right side, I still get the wrong answer

Comment: You need to multiply by the inverse on the left. That is, $x = \begin{pmatrix} 4 & -2 \\ -4 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} -3 & 2 \\ -9 & -3 \end{pmatrix}.$

Comment: That was the problem, I was using the wrong matrix for the inverse, however your right matrix is incorrect.
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        3 & -2  \\
        9 & 3  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Using that matrix gives the correct answer

Comment: My right matrix is correct assuming the question you wrote is correct. If you meant to solve $$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -5 & -9  \\
        -6 & -2  \\
        \end{bmatrix}   X +  \begin{bmatrix}
        -3 & 2  \\
        -9 & -3  \\
        \end{bmatrix}   =  \begin{bmatrix}
        -9 & -7  \\
        -2 & -3  \\
        \end{bmatrix}   X
$$ 
(note the plus sign in the left side) then the right matrix should be negated.

Comment: If you move the x to the left side and the regular matrix to the right, the Matrix would be negated, resulting in 
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        3 & -2  \\
        9 & 3  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

This is the result of the
 $$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0  \\
        0 & 0  \\
        \end{bmatrix} -    \begin{bmatrix}
        -3 & 2  \\
        -9 & -3  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: @Gyfe: That is correct... but in your original question, you asked about $$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -5 & -9  \\
        -6 & -2  \\
        \end{bmatrix}   X -   \begin{bmatrix}
        -3 & 2  \\
        -9 & -3  \\
        \end{bmatrix}   =  \begin{bmatrix}
        -9 & -7  \\
        -2 & -3  \\
        \end{bmatrix}   X
$$ 
which means that the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} -3 & 2 \\ -9 & -3 \end{pmatrix}$ should be added and not subtracted from both sides of the equation...

Comment: Yes that was my mistake, sorry

Answer (score 0):

The +/- signs are wrong on various places. RHS should just be the matrix displayed, because it already has - sign.

Also with the matrix before x you made a sign error

Answer (score 0):

You have made a few mistakes in signs while reversing the sides.

You should have approached the problem as follows:

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -5 & -9  \\
        -6 & -2  \\
        \end{bmatrix}   x -   \begin{bmatrix}
        -3 & 2  \\
        -9 & -3  \\
        \end{bmatrix}   =  \begin{bmatrix}
        -9 & -7  \\
        -2 & -3  \\
        \end{bmatrix}   x
$$

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -5x & -9x  \\
        -6x & -2x  \\
        \end{bmatrix}    -   \begin{bmatrix}
        -3 & 2  \\
        -9 & -3  \\
        \end{bmatrix}   =  \begin{bmatrix}
        -9x & -7x  \\
        -2x & -3x  \\
        \end{bmatrix}   
$$

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -5x+3 & -9x-2  \\
        -6x+9 & -2x+3  \\
        \end{bmatrix}  =  \begin{bmatrix}
        -9x & -7x  \\
        -2x & -3x  \\
        \end{bmatrix}   
$$

By the equality of the matrices, we can say that the corresponding elements are the same.

But there is no $x \in \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies the above equality.

Comment: I was under the impression that OP was looking for a matrix $x$, not a scalar.

Comment: @Roland OP did not mention if x is a matrix or a scalar. But I think you are right.

Comment: There is no $x \in \mathbb R$ that satisfies the OP equation; it certainly is not the case for $x=-3/4$.

Comment: @ZoranLoncarevic Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You have formally
$$ AX +B = CX$$
You should proceed as follows
$$ \begin{array}{rll}
 AX + B &=& CX \\
  B &=& CX - AX \\
  B &=& (C- A)X \\
(C-A)^{-1}  B &=& (C-A)^{-1} (C- A)X \\
(C-A)^{-1}  B &=& X \\
 \end{array} $$
Now $$ C-A = -\begin{bmatrix} 9 & 7 \\ 2 &3  \end{bmatrix}
 - (-\begin{bmatrix} 5 & 9 \\ 6 &2  \end{bmatrix})
= \begin{bmatrix} -4 & 2 \\ 4 & -1  \end{bmatrix}  $$
Then $$ (C-A)^{-1} = -\begin{bmatrix} 1/4 & 1/2 \\ 1 &1  \end{bmatrix} $$
 and  by $ (C-A)^{-1} B=X$ the result

> $$ (C-A)^{-1} B = - \begin{bmatrix} 21/4 & 1 \\ 12 &1  \end{bmatrix} = X $$